# Tricky statement about limits, TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: calculus, limits

In a homework sheet with true or false questions I have found the folowing statement

> $\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\left[ f(x+h)-f(x) \right]=0$
>
> Is this True OR False?

At the first sight of it True seems the right answer but then this came to my mind.

If $f$ is not continuous at $x$ then
$$\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)\neq f(x_0)$$

so applying the same logic to our example, suggests that False is the right answer

---

It seems a silly question but I need a second opinion.

Comment: Yes, the statement is FALSE in general. It is true if and only if the function $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck If this is truly all the information given in the question then you're right it is slightly ambiguous. The question should really specify exactly what $f$ is. For example, can $f$ be assumed to be any real valued function, any continuous function, etc. However, in any case, you only need to find one counter example to prove something false. With the information given I'd guess $f$ is assumed to be any function. And the statement is not true given any function, making the statement false, even though you can find specific functions that make it true.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No, it does not need to be ALL TRUE or ALL FALSE. It may also be CONDITIONALLY TRUE, based on something not clarified in the statement. In this case, it depends on the function $f$. For some $f$'s the statement is true, for others it is false. In mathematical logic we call something like $f$ here a "free variable." If a free variable may make a statement false and you ask if the statement is true or false, we say it is false. I.e. CONDITIONALLY TRUE we call FALSE. For more details, see a text on mathematical logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is false. Consider $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Then $$\lim_{h\to 0}[f(h)-f(0)]=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: I agree that this is true if $f$ is continuous, but since the question doesn't specify that, I would interpret the problem as "for all $f$ and for all $h$."

Comment: The definition of "statement," in math, is that it is either true or false. If it is true, then it is always true. If not, it is false.

Answer (score 0):

That is not true for all functions. That is, there exist counterexamples. For example, consider:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x=0\\1,&x\ne0\end{cases}$$
Then, the statement is false for $x=0$:
$$\lim_{h\to0}[f(0+h)-f(0)]=\\\lim_{h\to0}[1-0]=1$$
So there's an $f$ and an $x$ for which the statement is false.